# UPDATE each item in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble figuring out a solution to this.  I have several tables in my database with attributes having a `date` type.  However, in one of my tables I was not thinking during the design process so the attribute is not of `date` but is a `varchar`.  The dates in the "incorrect" table is formatted as dd-MMM-yyyy whereas all of the other dates are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd.

How can I run through the "incorrect" column and do `CAST(myDate AS date)` on each mis-typed attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd migrate to a `date` column.

1. Add a nullable `date` column
2. Run an update query to set the value of each column to the result of your cast
3. Drop the `varchar` column
4. Refactor your code or rename the new column to the name of the old one

Comment: That got it.  I was initially creating an entirely new table and trying to copy casted contents into it, then copy them back to the old table. Was running into errors with that. This worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Alternately, you can do this:  "ALTER TABLE <table> ALTER COLUMN <column> TYPE DATE USING <column>::DATE;" to do it all in one step.